# Php PDO | how to use fetchAll with FETCH_LAZY?

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to use FETCH_LAZY. I can use a while loop whilst setting $row equal to $query->fetch(). The problem is that fetchAll does not work when the fetchMode is FETCH_LAZY.

How can I return an array of PDO Objects?

Thanks.

Comment: Show us some code that you've tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the very nature of [FETCH_LAZY](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_LAZY), you cannot use `fetchAll` with this mode. It can be used with `fetch()` only.

It seems that you are simply confusing this mode with **FETCH_OBJ** which will give you an array of objects you need

```
$array = $stmt->fethAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Also note that beside creating stdObj instances you can make fetchAll to [return an array of objects of any other class](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/objects) as well.